# Solicitando ajuda em converter para selectOneMenu JSF

Tags: jsf-2.2, conversão

Observem a figura;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em salvar ele gera essa mensagem de erro em tela, que indica que não foi possível utilizar um conversor nulo, dizendo que não existe um converso nulo para a caixa de seleção mostrada na figura, pois o converso converteria a lista em um objeto do tipo cidade, porém existe sim uma classe que converte essa lista, e que inclusive essa mesma classe está sendo usada em outro managerBean e está funcionando perfeitamento, só não está funcionando neste formulário, veja abaixo;

```
package br.com.terezinha.adm.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Cidade;
import br.com.terezinha.adm.repository.Cidades;
import br.com.terezinha.adm.util.cdi.CDIServiceLocator;

@FacesConverter(value="estadoConverter", forClass = Cidade.class)
public class CidadeConverter implements Converter {

    private Cidades cidades;

    public CidadeConverter() {
        cidades = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(Cidades.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Cidade retorno = null;
        if (value != null) {
            Long id = new Long(value);
            retorno = cidades.porId(id);
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            Cidade cidade = (Cidade) value;
            return cidade.getCidadeId() == null ? null : cidade.getCidadeId().toString();


//          if (cidade.getCidadeId() != null) {
//              return cidade.getCidadeId().toString();
//          } else if (cidade.getCidadePai() != null) {
//                  return cidade.getCidadePai().toString();
//          }
//          else if(cidade.getSubCidades() !=null){
//              return cidade.getSubCidades().toString();
//          }
//          else{
//              return null;
//          }

        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

Não consigo entender porque isso está acontecendo, já fiz várias tentativas de correção como vocês podem ver.

já tentei até desta forma;

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="cidades" value="#{cadastroLocalidadeBean.cidadePai}" converter="estadoConverter"  >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a Bairro" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroLocalidadeBean.subcidades}"
        var="subcidade" itemValue="#{subcidade}"
        itemLabel="#{subcidade.descCidade}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

E nenhum resultado.

Alguém teria uma sugestão?

Aqui está o meu projeto no GitHub;

https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Terezinha.Adm

Comment: Seu objeto tem o método toString() definido?

Comment: sua pergunta foi tão técnica que nem entendi, mas acabei de atualizar minha postagem e incluir o caminho do meu projeto no GitHub, acredito que assim será mais fácil para mim ajuda.

Comment: O objeto cidade não precisa de um método toString definido para funcionar, somente basta uma classe converte para resolver isso, mas a classe converte não está resolvendo. agora eu não entendi porque o objeto cidade deveria ter um método toString? poderia responder essa pergunta?

Comment: eu perguntei se tinha o toString porque quando você coloca no itemValue ele pode mandar o retorno do toString() e não o objeto.

Comment: qual seria a sua sugestão?

Comment: Eu to achando que seu converter não está conseguindo buscar a cidade e está retornando null. Em nenhum exemplo de converter que vi tem o construtor do converter, provavelmente ele não etá inicializando sua Cidades.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado.